# How to show a previously signed document to the next signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following signing order for an envelope (composite template):

Template A (Signer1) -> Template B (Signer 2)

What I'm trying to accomplish is Signer 2 to be able see Tamplate A with signed information and sign Template B.

How can I achive this?

[edit 1]
Here is a call example:

Note1: each template includes a single document
Note2: each signer is defined on the template as follows: Signer1 ->1 and Signer2 ->5

I'm trying to not allow Signer1 to see Document2, and Signer2 to see the signed Template1 while signing Template2.

```
{
"emailSubject": "Subject",
"emailBlurb": "Body",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "templateId_1"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "EMAIL 1",
                            "name": "NAME 1",
                            "clientUserId": "",
                            "RecipientId": "ID 1",
                            "roleName": "Signer1",
                            "RoutingOrder": "1",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                   ...
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "carbonCopies": []
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "2",
                "templateId": "templateId_2"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "3",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "EMAIL 2",
                            "name": "NAME 2",
                            "clientUserId": "",
                            "RecipientId": "ID 2",
                            "roleName": "Signer2",
                            "RoutingOrder": "0",
                            "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Subject",
                                "emailBody": "Body"
                            },
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                    ... 
                                ]
                            }
                        },                            {
                            "email": "EMAIL 1",
                            "name": "NAME 1",
                            "clientUserId": "",
                            "RecipientId": "ID 1",
                            "roleName": "Signer1",
                            "excludedDocuments": [
                                1
                            ],
                            "RoutingOrder": "0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "carbonCopies": []
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

EnforceSignerVisibility is set to true because I want to exclude document 1 from user ID 1.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @InbarGazit I've added a call example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one envelope that includes both templates. Use composite templates to do this. Then set signing order and signer 2 will see what signer 1 signed.

### Updated

Re:

> I'm trying to not allow Signer1 to see Document2, and Signer2 to see the signed Template1 while signing Template2.

See [Document Visibility](https://www.google.com/search?q=docusign+document+visibility) documentation and examples. It enables you to have certain documents visible to some, not all signers.

Comment: I do have that approach. Added a call example in the description.